# Understanding an Einsum usage for graph convolution

Tags: pytorch

I am reading the code for the spatial-temporal graph convolution operation here:
https://github.com/yysijie/st-gcn/blob/master/net/utils/tgcn.py and I'm having some difficulty understanding what is happening with an einsum operation. In particular

For `x` a tensor of shape `(N, kernel_size, kc//kernel_size, t, v)`, where
kernel_size is typically 3, and lets say `kc=64*kernel_size`, `t` is the number of frames, say 64, and `v` the number of vertices, say 25. `N` is the batch size.

Now for a tensor `A` of shape (3, 25, 25) where each dimension is a filtering op on the graph vertices, an einsum is computed as:

```
x = torch.einsum('nkctv,kvw->nctw', (x, A))
```

I'm not sure how to interpret this expression. What I think it's saying is that for each batch element, for each channel `c_i` out of 64, sum each of the three matrices obtained by matrix multiplication of the (64, 25) feature map at that channel with the value of `A[i]`. Do I have this correct? The expression is a bit of a mouthful, and notation wise there seems to be a bit of a strange usage of `kc` as one variable name, but then decomposition of `k` as kernel size and `c` as the number of channels (192//3 = 64) in the expression for the einsum. Any insights appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helps when you look closely at the notation:

- `nkctv` for left side
- `kvw` on the right side
- `nctw` being the result

Missing from the result are:

- `k`
- `v`

These elements are summed together into a single value and squeezed, leaving us the resulting shape.

Something along the lines of (expanded shapes (added 1s) are broadcasted and sum per element):

- left: `(n, k, c, t, v, 1)`
- right: `(1, k, 1, 1,  v, w)`

Now it goes (l, r for left and right):

- `torch.mul(l, r)`
- `torch.sum(l, r, dim=(1, 4))`
- squeeze any singular dimensions

It is pretty hard to get, hence Einstein's summation helps in terms of thinking about resulting shapes “mixed” with each other, at least for me.

Comment: This is a great explanation. So if I understand correctly, first you match the shape of both tensors through unsqueeze operations. Then you multiply the two tensors (element-wise), and sum across the dimensions missing from the output after the arrow in the notation.

Answer (score 1):

```
Y = torch.einsum('nkctv,kvw->nctw', (x, A)) means:
```

[einsum interpretation on graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbITK.png)

For better understanding, I have replaced the `x` in left hand side with `Y`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).